# react creating generic input component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to make a generic input component using hooks but not 100% sure how to implement this.

So I have a parent component

```
const Parent = () => {
   const [team, setTeam] = useState('');
   return <Input onChange={???} value={team} />
}
```

and then my `Input` component looks like this.

```
const Input = ({onChange}) => {
   return <input onChange={onChange} />
}
```

I am wondering where the state should be stored. Is it in the `Parent` component, or in the `Input` or do both need to store state?

Comment: Why do you insist on using hooks? A class component would make it much easier

Comment: Why do you insist on using a class component ? A hook would make it much easier @DorShinar

Comment: Because you can't bind functions in a functional component. The performance benefit from not binding might be negligible in some cases, but in other it could slow the application.

Comment: @DorShinar because I'm riding on the HOOKS hype train , don't get left behind brother 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use an arrow function bound to your `onChange` event. Then use the `setTeam` callback given in your hook inside of it :

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [team, setTeam] = useState('');
    return <Input onChange={ev => setTeam(ev.target.value)} value={team} />
}
```

Also, avoid having redundant state values. Any information should only be stored in the component it is used in.

The shortened `Input` code :

```
const Input = ({ onChange, value }) => <input onChange={onChange} value={value} />
```

Or :

```
const Input = props => <input {...props} />
```

Comment: If the parent component will be rendered often, creating the callbacks over and over again could impact performance

Comment: and is input just `const Input = () => (<input />);`

Comment: I am seeing the following error:  Failed prop type: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.

Comment: It seems that the function you passed is undefined

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to use arrow functions in `onChange` to bind callbacks. A better way is to bind in the constructor or directly on the class field.

Comment: This is not a class component, this is a hook.